# What modseq value to cache?

Tags: imap

I'm reading [RFC 7162](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7162), trying to figure out how a client should behave when communicating with a server that supports `CONDSTORE` but not `QRESYNC`.

The initial connection case is simple enough: the client compares its cached modseq value with the `HIGHESTMODSEQ` response to the `SELECT` command, and if it is lower, the client can retrieve any changes with `FETCH` + `CHANGEDSINCE` or `SEARCH` + `MODSEQ`.  After doing that, the client can store the `HIGHESTMODSEQ` value as its new cached modseq value for the mailbox.

However, if the client receives unsolicited `FETCH` responses while the mailbox is selected, can it draw any reliable conclusions from the `MODSEQ` attributes in these updates?  Would it be safe to cache the highest seen `MODSEQ` value, or would the client risk missing any updates to the mailbox state in doing so?

Comment: If you are already synchronized, by using FETCH+CHANGEDSINCE, you should be safe to cache any MODSEQ seen after that, since presumably you have seen all changes from HIGHESTMODSEQ until now.  Note, if you switch folders and come back, you would need to resynchronize.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky.

The question probably refers to a language in RFC7162 which clarifies that `HIGHESTMODSEQ` and `MODSEQ` are two different beasts, and that a `FETCH MODSEQ` might arrive while a server is forced to withdraw some `EXPUNGE`s, maybe because the client sent a command which uses MSNs (see [motivation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7162#section-3.2) in chapter 3.2).

In this particular case where the server is said to only support `CONDSTORE` and *not* `QRESYNC`, the `MODSEQ` and `HIGHESTMODSEQ` are only used for keeping track of metadata changes (such as `FLAGS` updates). They do *not* have to change on message expunges. The situation which the RFC is trying to prevent because of QRESYNC therefore can happen without any fatal consequences as you as a client *cannot* use `HIGHESTMODSEQ` for any other purpose but `FLAGS` updates. Based on that, I don't see a reason why a client shouldn't bump `HIGHESTMODSEQ` on a `CONDSTORE`-only server upon seeing a `MODSEQ`.

You should probably ask on the imap-protocol mailing list and seek clarification. I, too, have an open bug about how to deal with this properly, and the RFC is not completely clear to me.